# How can I give string to Terminal with space in between?

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to make this code works correctly, but for unknown reason for me it makes `New` instead `New Folder`, how can I solve the issue?

```
bash -c "echo ""hello world""; cd ${HOME}; cd Desktop; ls; mkdir ""New Folder"";echo ""Folder is Successfully created! """ > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Note it's not really "to terminal". The entity that interprets the quotes first is whatever shell you're using, the one that is going to spawn `bash -c …` (so it may or may not be Bash). Your [terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/108618) is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Your concern is the string with spaces but there is another general issue (I won't write an answer because it's not the issue you're asking about). Shell code should be single quoted. Either let the *inner* shell expand `$HOME` (`bash -c '… "$HOME" …'`) or let the outer shell expand `$HOME` and pass the value as an *argument* to the inner shell, not as code that will be *interpreted again* (`bash -c '… "$1" …' bash "$HOME"`). The first method works because `HOME` is (usually) in the environment. Your method allows code injection. The value of `$HOME` is usually safe, but in general (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) in general `$var` may expand to a string containing `"`, `$(reboot)` or anything that may be interpreted by the inner shell as *code*. If you really want to do this like you did and if your outer shell is Bash then use `${var@Q}` (`bash -c "… ${var@Q} …"`, inner quotes will be added by `Q`). Again, your value of `$HOME` is most likely safe, but don't get used to your method because sooner or later you will use it with a potentially unsafe variable. The three metods I gave you are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubling the quotation marks *does not* act as an "escape" in Bash (the way it would in CSV or VBScript) – instead it behaves more like in C or Python, where you just end up with several string literals concatenated together.

In Bash (or C or Python), whenever you use `""` inside the string, the first `"` just closes the quoted literal and the second `"` opens a new one. You end up with these strings joined together:

```
"echo "
"hello world"
"; cd ${HOME}; cd Desktop; ls; mkdir "
"New Folder"
";echo "
"Folder is Successfully created! "
""
```

And the result is the same as:

```
"echo hello world; cd ${HOME}; cd Desktop; ls; mkdir New Folder;echo Folder is Successfully created! "
```

The actual escape character in Bash is **backslash `\`**, and to write a literal double-quote you need to use **`\"`** like this:

```
"echo \"hello world\"; cd ${HOME}; cd Desktop; ls; mkdir \"New Folder\";echo \"Folder is Successfully created! \""
```

(You should probably use `cd \"\${HOME}\"` as well, or `cd ~/Desktop`.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use single quotes inside double quotes or escape double
quotes. Additionally, use `&&`
instead of `;` to run the next command only if the previous one
succeeds:

```
bash -c "echo hello world && cd ${HOME} && cd Desktop && ls && mkdir \"New Folder\" && echo Folder is Successfully created!"
```

Comment: I do not get what you said about `single quotes inside double quotes` but you are using double as well, what I am missing?

Comment: I said _or_ ...